# LAMP Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I installed LAMP on Ubuntu 10.04. Now whenever I try to access http://localhost/ I get this message:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I tried changing the permissions of the var/www/ folder by clicking ALT-f2, typing in "gksu nautilus" and right clicking the folder and changing the permissions but I still get a 403 forbidden error.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You likely don't have an index document and directory indexing isn't turned on for that directory. Try adding `index.html` to your web root directory.

Comment: I do have an index.html file in the www/ directory. How would I turn on directory indexing.

Comment: You'll want to turn on the `Indexes` option. Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options (and there's an example of usage in @Mart's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Do check how your www folder is configured in the httpd.conf file too. Particularly this line (copied directly from my own home web-server):

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Comment: where is the httpd.conf file located?

Comment: wait...I found it in /etc/apache2/ However, there's nothing in the text file. What should I do?